# CP2102 bypass capacitors

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, cp2102

I'm using planning to use CP2102 as an USB/UART transceiver. Datasheet (can be found here: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf) on page 21 shows example of self-powered  schematic, and that's exactly my scenario: external 3.3V LDO regulator which feeds several ICs on the board, including CP2102. In this case divider circuit is needed in order CP2102 could safely detect USB Vbus presence. However, same picture shows that in total 4 decoupling capacitors are required, 2 on Vdd pin, and 2 on REGIN input to internal 3.3V regulator.
[image]

But these two pins are physically adjacent to each other, see picture below:
[image]

Do I really need to use 4 caps? Or I can connect these two pins by a trace, and use 2 capacitors for decoupling?
My schematic for this part of the board so far is below:
[image]

Also, can I omit resistor from 3.3V to RESET pin? It would be very convenient to connect them directly by short trace underneath the chip.

Comment: I gather you are designing a pcb. If you decide to cut corners and find you have problems, who will you blame? You'll have to spin the pcb again with the fixes. Note how Silabs have drawn thier schematic vs yours. In terms of the connections, they may be identical, but if you view each track as a resistor and inductor, then the schematics are very different. Whether the CP2102 regulator is very sensitive that it would make a difference, we probably don't know. The board in front of me with a CP2102 chip has all the capacitors. For the sake of 1 resistor, I wouldn't omit the pullup on reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMD ceramics of the same package size have the same inductance, therefore adding 100nF in parallel with 1µF will only provide better HF performance (ie, lower inductance) if the 100nF cap is in a smaller package than the 1µF cap, say a 0603 1µF cap and a 0201 100nF cap. If you use two caps of the same size, it will perform worse than one 1µF cap due to antiresonance.

So, if you use all 0603 caps, the simplest solution is to use only one 1µF ceramic, but take care in placing and routing it correctly.

[image]

With 4 layer the optimum is: a small copper pour for the VDD/REGIN, then two vias to ground plane on layer2 to link to the chip's ground powerpad.

If you are extra paranoid, you can put one cap per pin. In this case put the one for 5V IN on the left of the one I drew, with a little bit of trace. Since an internal regulator can tolerate more voltage drop than the internal chip VCC, it makes sense to put Vcore cap closer and the LDO input cap further.

Note that a 2mm bit of 0.5mm wide trace between the pin and the cap will have 1nH inductance, which is about the same as a properly mounted cap. So if you insist on putting 2 caps in parallel "because 100nF is better at HF" but you must use longer traces because it doesn't fit, then it's pointless. Hence the bit of copper pour, which is much less inductive.

If you use 2-layer board, then ground plane will be 1.6mm away instead of 0.1-0.2mm, in this case it makes no difference which side of the board the cap is on since the current loop will go through the whole board thickness anyway, so if you put components on both sides, you can also put the cap on the back. In this case it would be better to use one via per power pin (or 2 caps) ; after all the manufacturer bothered to use two power pins, probably to prevent the current from one from coupling into the other.

If you already have a 3V3 LDO then there is probably enough capacitance on the output already that it would make double duty with the 4.7µF cap, so see what caps you have on your board already. Note 4.7µF tantalum caps with huge ESR are mostly for decoration and damping resonances...

Answer (score 1):

Reset may not be directly connected to 3V3, it is an open-drain input/output so it must be pulled up via resistor.

And since the power pins are next to each other, you can draw all four caps but mount only two to verify the operation. Or mount two 100nF caps and single 4.7uF capacitor. There is no way to guess which capacitors or how much is needed for proper operation though, so manufacturer suggestions should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet notes indicate “ A 4.7 μF capacitor can be added if powering other devices from the on-chip regulator”

Comment: And since it is a self-powered device, the onboard regulator will not be powering any other devices, as the regulator is bypassed and external 3.3V is fed into the device. Should your answer be interpreted that the 4.7uF capacitor can be omitted? The capacitor is still there in the other diagrams too, as in the original post.

Comment: @justme page 9 option 2.

Comment: Page 15 fig 5 Note 2 and yes  omitted if no external load is stated, but compare your step load regulation expectations with 38 Ohm source R for RC response.

Comment: @Passerby I can read the datasheet but what do you mean by quoting that to me? It says if powering other devices from on-chip regulator, which is not the case here. The on-chip regulator is unused as 3V3 is fed into this chip from external regulator. All diagrams still have the capacitor, even if the on-chip regulatoe is used. That is why I asked clarification how this answer should be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the datasheet, everything you are asking about are recommendations.

The 4.7k pull up is optional for noise immunity. You can leave this unconnected. The silicone labs evaluation board schematic has this only connected to a test point.
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/CP2102-EK.pdf

The 4.7 uF capacitor is optional if you are using the internal 5V to 3.3V regulator to power other things. I.e. using VDD as an output.

The Regin 1 uF and 0.1 uF are recommended if using the regulator.

And the Regin connection to 3.3V/VDD is also just a recommendation.

Obviously they are making recommendations based on potential issues with noise or rapidly changing power needs. But if your circuit has a good power source and isn't say rapidly cycle motors then the noise suppression is likely unneeded.

You can as suggested add in the footprints and only populate if you see issues.